$H^2$-elliptic regularity (up to the boundary) for operators with lower order terms for Lipschitz/convex domains
Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain which is Lipschitz or convex. Given an elliptic operator of the form
$$\langle Au, v \rangle = a_{ij}u_{x_i}v_{x_j} + b_i u_{x_i}v + cuv$$
are there any elliptic regularity results in the sense that
$$\lVert u \rVert_{H^2(\Omega)}$$ can be bounded by the $L^2$-norm of $Au$ and potentially the $H^1$ norm of $u$?
In Grisvard, the result for convex domains is only for elliptic operators without any lower order terms. I have seen results with lower order terms but only for $C^{1,1}$ domains (in Gilbarg and Trudinger). Is there a citation which fills the gap? If the result doesn't hold for such domains, what's the minimal regularity I'd need?

In Grisvard you find estimates for the problem in divergence-form, and the result will still hold with the lower-order terms: they are $L^2$, so just put them on the right-hand side.
The general case with $a_{ij}$ outside the Hessian expression ist much more difficult. In general there is hardly any control for irregular coefficients, and you need restrictions on these, such as the Cordes condition.
There is a nice book on the topic.
Maugeri, Palagachev, Softova: Elliptic and parabolic equations with discontinuous coefficients. Zbl 0958.35002
The Cordes condition was generalized to lower order terms by Smears, Süli: SINUM 2014, Zbl 1304.65252
Summarizing, there are some results for the non divergence case when it comes to estimates up to the boundary, but the theory is not as complete as in the divergence case.
Edit: If you are willing to accept $W^{1,\infty}$ regularity for $a$, as is essentially required by Grisvard, you obtain a corresponding result for the non divergence case by using the product rule in the 2nd order term. This is not the interesting case, though.
